# Delphi TTask get data from main thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi

From what I have understood reading Nick Hodges, this code should be fine:

```
TTask.Run(
  procedure
  var
    resp, tmp: string;
    req: boolean;
    bwriter: TBinaryWriter;
    myfile: TFileStream;
  begin
    //tell the user to wait
    TThread.Queue(TThread.CurrentThread,
      procedure
      begin
        LoginButton.Text := 'Please wait...';
      end
    );

    //some checks
    try
      resp := GetURL('... here I get a result from the server...');
      if (resp = fOKstatus) then
      begin
        req := true;

        myfile := TFileStream.Create(TPath.Combine(TPath.GetHomePath, 'docs.mkb'), fmCreate);
        try
          bwriter := TBinaryWriter.Create(myfile, TEncoding.Unicode, false);
          try
            bwriter.Write(UsernameEdit.Text);
            bwriter.Write(AppIDEdit.Text);
            bwriter.Close;
          finally
            bwriter.Free;
          end;
        finally
          myfile.Free;
        end;
      end
      else
      begin
        req := false;
      end;
    except
      req := false;
    end;

    //final
    TThread.Queue(TThread.CurrentThread,
      procedure
      begin
        if (req = true) then
        begin
          LoginButton.Text := 'Success!';
          ShowMessage('Close the app to complete the registration.');
        end
        else
        begin
          LoginButton.Text := 'Login failed.';
        end;
      end
    );

  end
);
```

This runs in a separated thread, and it is linked to the main thread with the calls to `Queue()`. In fact, at the beginning I am updating the `Text` of a Button using this method.

---

QUESTION. Look at these 2 lines:

```
bwriter.Write(UsernameEdit.Text);
bwriter.Write(AppIDEdit.Text);
```

I need to retrieve the username and AppID (which is a random code) from two Edit controls that are in the main thread UI. Is this correct?

I guess that I should call `Queue()`, but so far the program is working well.

Can I take the values in this way safely? I am not updating anything, and I just need to grab the data, but I am not sure if mixing contents from 2 different tasks can be dangerous/bad practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2 lines of code you are concerned about are NOT thread-safe.  You **must** synchronize with the main thread for *all* UI access, both reading and writing.  `TThread.Queue()` is *asynchronous*, so it is not suitable for the purpose of retrieving values from the UI.  Use `TThread.Synchronize()` instead, which is *synchronous*:

```
TTask.Run(
  procedure
  var
    resp, tmp, username, appid: string;
    req: boolean;
    bwriter: TBinaryWriter;
    myfile: TFileStream;
  begin
    //tell the user to wait
    TThread.Queue(nil,
      procedure
      begin
        LoginButton.Text := 'Please wait...';
      end
    );

    //some checks
    try
      resp := GetURL('... here I get a result from the server...');
      if resp = fOKstatus then
      begin
        req := true;

        TThread.Synchronize(nil,
          procedure
          begin
            username := UsernameEdit.Text;
            appid := AppIDEdit.Text;
          end
        );

        myfile := TFileStream.Create(TPath.Combine(TPath.GetHomePath, 'docs.mkb'), fmCreate);
        try
          bwriter := TBinaryWriter.Create(myfile, TEncoding.Unicode, false);
          try
            bwriter.Write(username);
            bwriter.Write(appid);
            bwriter.Close;
          finally
            bwriter.Free;
          end;
        finally
          myfile.Free;
        end;
      end
      else
      begin
        req := false;
      end;
    except
      req := false;
    end;

    //final
    TThread.Queue(nil,
      procedure
      begin
        if req then
        begin
          LoginButton.Text := 'Success!';
          ShowMessage('Close the app to complete the registration.');
        end
        else
        begin
          LoginButton.Text := 'Login failed.';
        end;
      end
    );
  end
);
```

Alternatively, assuming the main UI thread is the one starting the `TTask`, you can read the 2 values before starting the `TTask` and let the anonymous procedure capture them:

```
var
  username, appid: string;
begin
  username := UsernameEdit.Text;
  appid := AppIDEdit.Text;

  TTask.Run(
    procedure
    var
      resp, tmp: string;
      req: boolean;
      bwriter: TBinaryWriter;
      myfile: TFileStream;
    begin
      //tell the user to wait
      TThread.Queue(nil,
        procedure
        begin
          LoginButton.Text := 'Please wait...';
        end
      );

      //some checks
      try
        resp := GetURL('... here I get a result from the server...');
        if resp = fOKstatus then
        begin
          req := true;

          myfile := TFileStream.Create(TPath.Combine(TPath.GetHomePath, 'docs.mkb'), fmCreate);
          try
            bwriter := TBinaryWriter.Create(myfile, TEncoding.Unicode, false);
            try
              bwriter.Write(username);
              bwriter.Write(appid);
              bwriter.Close;
            finally
              bwriter.Free;
            end;
          finally
            myfile.Free;
          end;
        end
        else
        begin
          req := false;
        end;
      except
        req := false;
      end;

      //final
      TThread.Queue(nil,
        procedure
        begin
          if req then
          begin
            LoginButton.Text := 'Success!';
            ShowMessage('Close the app to complete the registration.');
          end
          else
          begin
            LoginButton.Text := 'Login failed.';
          end;
        end
      );
    end
  );
end;
```

Comment: Ok you solved my doubt :) but why you are not calling TThread.CurrentThread and you are using nil instead?

Comment: When the first parameter of `TThread.Queue()` is not `nil`, the queued operation is linked to the specified thread, and when that thread terminates the operation is *cancelled* if it has not already been processed (the thread calls `TThread.RemoveQueuedEvents()` on itself). Since `Queue()` is asynchronous, that could lead to unperformed operations if you are not careful. Passing `nil` instead avoids that pitfall.  As for `TThread.Synchronize()`, the same parameter  is basically redundant and useless.  I have never had a good reason to pass a non-`nil` pointer to either method.

Comment: I guess that I should do the same (setting the nil) even if I am using the Execute in a subclass of TThread? And from what I have understood in your comment using nil in both is the best choice right? Very helpful Remy btw, thank you

Comment: In a `TThread` derived class, you generally would not use the static versions of `Queue()`/`Synchronize()`, you would use the instance versions instead, which do not have the `AThread` parameter since they rely on the `Self` pointer instead.  The static versions are meant to be used when called from outside of a `TThread` class (such as `TTask`, or in a non-Delphi thread).

Comment: Ok so I have to use the nil only when I use TTasks, not when I use a derived. Thanks again ;)

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with `TTask` specifically.  It has to do with whether you call the static vs non-static version of `Queue()`/`Synchronize()`, that's all.  It just happens that your `TTask` code is calling the static versions.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, you also could help me with my last question please?