# Delphi queue and synchronize parameters

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I have posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42496767/delphi-ttask-get-data-from-main-thread) that confused me about the multi threading and I haven't found an answer online. Let's say that I have created something like `TTest = class(TThread)` and so you can imagine that I have an *Execute*. Inside it I can call:

```
Synchronize(procedure
            begin
             //code
            end);


Queue(procedure
            begin
             //code
            end);
```

From what I have understood the code above should have another hidden parameter before the anonymous method, the `Self`. Suppose that now I am not in a derived class (like TTest) and I am in a button click event. I can call this:

```
TTask.Run(
    procedure
    begin

      TThread.Queue(nil,
        procedure
        begin
          testB.Text := 'Please wait...';
        end;

        TThread.Queue(nil,
        procedure
        begin
          testB.Text := 'Please wait MORE...';
        end;

      end);
```

Here I have used nil as parameter because (if I'm correct) if I called the `TThread.CurrentThread`, when a Queue finishes the other would be removed due to RemoveQueuedEvents().

So my real question is: how do I determine when I have to pass `nil` or `TThread.CurrentThread`?

- I have understood that in a derived class of TThread like the TTest above I can call Queue/Sync with the anonymous method only because the `Self` comes to rescue.
- If I have to call Queue or Synchronize in a TTask.Run for example, am I sure that I have to use the nil parameter?

I am new to this kind of things so I find this pretty hard and I want to understand the concept otherwise I'll create broken apps. I see that Nick Hodges in his book is using nil and CurrentThread but I cannot figure why.

Answer (score 6):

Even inside a *TThread* descendants *Execute* method you can use the *Synchronize* and *Queue* overload with the *nil* parameter in front. While *Synchronize* is not affected, the call to *Queue* can be ignored for the same reason as in the other case when the thread finishes before the *Queue* is executed.

```
Synchronize(nil,
  procedure
  begin
    //code
  end);


Queue(nil,
  procedure
  begin
    //code
  end);
```

Comment: So if I ALWAYS used the nil parameter that won't be a danger? But still I need to know when the TThread.CurrentThread can be used.

Comment: I can see no need to use CurrentThread in any case. Actually you don't have access to that parameter inside the anonymous method anyway.

Comment: I just want my program to be thread safe, so you are confirming me that I can always use the nil as parameter. I'm going to accept

Comment: @RaffaeleRossi: Is there something unclear about what [I explained to you earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42496767/)? "*When the first parameter of `TThread.Queue()` is not nil, **the queued operation is linked to the specified thread, and when that thread terminates the operation is cancelled if it has not already been processed** (the thread calls `TThread.RemoveQueuedEvents()` on itself). ... Passing nil instead avoids that pitfall.*" ...

Comment: @RaffaeleRossi: In other words, if you want to *queue* an operation and just let it run, pass `nil`. If you want to *queue* an operation that should not outlive a given thread object (maybe because the operation accesses members of that thread, etc), then pass that thread object instead. It is as simply as that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: no it's just me that I find this topic not easy and a bit difficult to understand the english. Btw now its clear thank you all.